# Custome chrome tab when chrome not installed

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

How to handle the case if the app has implemented chrome custom tabs but chrome app is not installed on the device?

I installed my app on a device and when clicked a link the app crashed

Comment: Post your crash log.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the `Chrome Custom Tab` implemented App crashed because the `Chrome App` is not installed on the device. Then you can handle the case by checking if `Chrome App` is installed on the device.

```
String chromePackageName = "com.android.chrome";

boolean isChromeAppInstalled = false;

try {
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (null != list && 0 < list.size()) {
        for (PackageInfo info : list) {
            if (chromePackageName.equals(info.packageName)) {
                isChromeAppInstalled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {}

if (isChromeAppInstalled) {
    //Use Chrome Custom Tab
}
```